# visual studio 2013 cannot retrieve database objects

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Firstly, Visual Studio 2013 connects to database and retreive tables normaly. 
I added more table to database and edit relationship. After that I update data source in Project Explorer tree but it's failed. Even I tested the connection It's ok. But VS 2013 cannot retreive data objects - Message Box shows "Retreiving database object..." in very long time without reason. Can you show me how to fix it?
[image: VS 2013 can connect to database successfully]

[image: But VS 2013 cannot retreive data objects (tables)]

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to fix this error. Just only find and kill all of process are using database